# How can I destroy widget with mouse left click from outside of the specific entry in tkinter python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bind, tkinter-entry

I made a entry for rename the file.
When I click the file, the entry widget is open and I want I can destroy the widget when I click outside the entry widget, and if I click inside the widget, it should be not destroyed. The code is like below.

```
self.root.bind("<Button-1>", self.rename_cancel)

def rename_cancel(self, event):
    if self.rename_act_mpf == 1:
        self.rename_entry_mpf.destroy()
        self.rename_act_mpf = 0
    if self.rename_act_db == 1:
        self.rename_entry_db.destroy()
        self.rename_act_db = 0
```

in this code, when I click somewhere, the entry widget is destroyed even I click the inside of the widget. How can I make the exception for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.widget` will tell you which widget was clicked on. You can compare that to your entry widget, and call `destroy` if the click wasn't on the entry widget.